# Can managed vector db like pinecone support MMR

Tags: information-retrieval, faiss, pinecone

To get diversity in the search results, I want to use max marginal relevance for this.

I want to fetch N documents form vector db similar to question, then subsequently I want to get documents which are similar to question but dissimilar to existing documents.

formula to get MMR would be.

```
new_similarity_formula = similarity(question) - max_over_existingdocs{similarity(document)}.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LangChain and DataStax Astra/Cassandra as the Vector DB, you can do something like this:

```
import cassio
cassio.init(token=os.environ["ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN"], database_id=os.environ["ASTRA_DB_ID"])

from langchain.vectorstores.cassandra import Cassandra
table_name = 'vs_investment_kb'
keyspace = 'demo'

retrieverMMR = CassVectorStore.as_retriever(
    search_type='mmr',
    search_kwargs={
        'k': 4,
        'fetch_k': 10,
    },
    return_source_documents=True
)

# Create a "RetrievalQA" chain
chainMMR = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=retrieverMMR,
    chain_type_kwargs={
        'prompt': PROMPT,
        'document_variable_name': 'summaries'
    }
)
# Run it and print results
responseMMR = chainMMR.run(QUERY)
print(responseMMR)
# Create a "RetrievalQA" chain
chainMMR = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=retrieverMMR,
    chain_type_kwargs={
        'prompt': PROMPT,
        'document_variable_name': 'summaries'
    }
)
# Run it and print results
responseMMR = chainMMR.run(QUERY)
print(responseSim)
```

Cassio is the library that enables you to interact with Astra/Cassandra without having to write CQL commands, it abstracts that for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).